# Unable to open an already opened port using Visual Serial Port Emulator

Tags: java, virtual-serial-port

I'm a beginner.  I'm trying to run 2 Java processes simultaneously using the VSP Emulator to open the same Com Port.  I have tried using the Connector device or the Splitter device.  The 2nd process is unable to open the previously opened port.  Is there anything else I need set to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open the same port twice.  There is no operating system I know of that allows you to open the same port twice.  The ports are how the OS routes incoming packets to the proper application.  You may want to read up on the [OSI Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).